# how much is it worth of hashing of passwords in java for security?

Tags: java, passwords, hash

I am developing a web application in **Java** and I want to make the authentication process secure
by using **hashed** passwords.

*In hashing*
**step-1 :** we take the password given by the user and add a **salt** to it.
**step-2 :** hash it using `MessageDigest` and store the hashed value in database

While authenticating a user during login process we repeat both the **same** steps above, but instead of
storing the hashed value we compare it with the value present in database.

Now *forgive my ignorance* but what I want to say is if a hacker gets access to the database by any other
means, then it can provide security as the hacker cannot get the real text of password from the hashed
value so easily.

**BUT** how can it provide security against other forms of attacks like `Bruteforce attack, Rainbow attack, dictionary attack` etc. as we use the **same** steps to authenticate the user for login?

I don't think hashing of passwords now-a-days value that much.
**Give me some suggestions.....** if I am wrong.

Comment: Salting has a *very specific use*. It doesn't solve many unrelated security problems, but it solves on problem very efficiently. That problem is dictionary attacks on the entire DB of hashed passwords. Other attacks (such as brute-forcing the login page) are not in the scope of what salted hashes *tries* to prevent.

Comment: The purpose of cryptography is not to make data inaccessible to the an *enemy*, but rather to make it difficult enough for the *enemy* to realize that the time and effort required are not really worth the trouble.

Comment: @mukund You say you add salt to the password in the first step. Please be more specific about what that salt represents.

Comment: Perhaps you might have a look at: [SRP](http://srp.stanford.edu/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brute force is brute force. You can't do anything about it except refusing to try the authentication (or imposing a delay) after N successive failed trials. Of course, if the hacker has the hashed password, he will be able to brute force the password, but the point of a secure hashing function is to make that very very long.

Rainbow/dictionary attacks are solved by the salting. If a user chooses "password" as his password, a rainbow/dictionary attack would find the password immediately. But since you salt the password with a random value, the hashed value will be something like `d7("58gd0}78sq5sQIazuAKpassword`, which won't be in the rainbow table/dictionary.

Comment: hmm.. that means different methodologies should be used to make your application secure from different types of security risks and hashing is there to protect from rainbow/dictionary attacks only. THANKS for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is right.
Hashed password *does not* provide any layer of security as there are many tools now available (such as [here](http://www.md5decrypt.org/), [here](http://www.md5decrypter.com/) and [here](http://www.hash-cracker.com/)) to get plain text based on reverse hashing and hashed directory.
I would suggest use [JBcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) that has salt property that you do not have to store in database, and since your salt does not be known to anyone, even you also, then it is very much difficult to un-hash and get plain text.

More information about BCrypt as on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)

Answer (score 0):

**Salting and Hashing**

It is process to make the password not readable by human and hard to get back the original password that user might use at other site such as credit card site.

**Authentication via Login**

Now your use case is hacker use normal login form to login via brute force, which is not salting and hashing password **supposed to do**, since it is you application logic to prevent multiple login using wrong credential.

**Conclusion**

It is your application resposible for prevent brute force login, but not by **salting and hashing** password.

Answer (score -1):

you can save application from Bruteforce attack, Rainbow attack, dictionary attack by enforcing strong password rules e.g. password should contain a combination of alphe numeric plus special characters such myPassWord$10

Comment: Actually length is much better than how many possibilities each letter can have.  You will find it easier to remember too if you don't have to remember which letter is a capital and which ones are numbers. best explained here http://xkcd.com/936/